# AWS first login can not find Account ID

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a docker on AWS. I have created a an account and now I am stuck on this page:

[image: AWS Sign-in page]

It asks for account ID and IAM username. I do not know my ID. Where is it?

On AWS docs it says log into your account and go to support center, but the support center login requires this same screen. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Check the mail you used to create the account, the account ID must have been sent to it

Comment: the account id is for non-root user i.e the users that are created via IAM. I believe this is your own account if yes the you should signin using the `signin using the roor creds link`

Answer (score 0):

Click the **Sign-in using root account credentials** link on the sign-in page and you will be prompted for an email address and password.

This will login as the Root account, which is all-powerful. In fact, it is so powerful that the recommendation is that you should immediately **create a new IAM User, assign it Admin permissions and then never use the Root login again**. You can assign Admin permissions by attaching the policy called `AdministratorAccess`.

While you are in the IAM console, you can create an **account alias** that you can use when logging in via the screen you have shown. It will also give you a URL you can use to access the correct sign-in page in future.